# How do I get code coverage for all branches using Pester?

Tags: code-coverage, chocolatey, pester

Multiple [test cases](https://github.com/030/chocolatey-1/blob/installchocolateyservice/tests/unit/Install-ChocolateyService.Tests.ps1) have been written to test a new Chocolatey function using Pester. How do check whether all branches have been covered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE 2:**

Thanks to oɔɯǝɹ for pointing out that Pester has now released a version of Pester that supporting code coverage.

**UPDATE 1:**

As of Pester Version 3.0, it is now possible to get code coverage information, using:

```
Invoke-Pester -CodeCoverage <path to file>
```

This is documented in the project wiki page:

https://github.com/pester/Pester/wiki/Code-Coverage

**NOTE:** In order to use this, you will require PowerShell version 3.0

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

To the best of my knowledge, Pester doesn't currently support code coverage analysis, but it is something that is being worked on.

There is an open issue for this feature here:

https://github.com/pester/Pester/issues/53

You can see it being worked on here:

http://davewyatt.wordpress.com/2014/06/29/code-coverage-analysis-for-pester-feedback-request/

And there is a screenshot of it working here:

https://twitter.com/nohwnd/status/485093995929157632

So basically, hold tight, and there will hopefully be something soon.

In terms of the actual Chocolatey code base, there is quite a good convention being used, namely that for each *.ps1 file, there "should" be a corresponding ".Tests.ps1 file. If this second file doesn't exist, then there are no unit tests for that function.

Comment: It depends on what the nunit stuff can do based on coverage.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ How so? My original answer clearly stated that no so functionality was available at the time of writing, with a clear link indicating a GitHub issue that could be watched to figure out when and where the functionality would be available.  If anyone has the right to feel agrevied it would be me, for you voting down an answer for no good reason.  I have merely updated my existing answer with the new state of play.

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ I think we will have to agree to disagree.  The answer was not incorrect or obsolete.  It provided all the information that any person wanting to find out the information would require.  Clicking on the link to the GitHub issue provided in the original answer provided the exact information that you give in your answer.

Comment: I fully admit I'm not sure what the SE etiquette states, but in a case of an outdated accepted answer, one could edit it with the updated information, versus downvoting and providing an answer that the original was leaning towards. Because it is accepted, if the answer is no longer accurate it helps the SE community the most if the answer is updated. Some folks won't look down and realize the newer, unaccepted answer is now the most relevant.

Comment: At the very least leave a comment that the answer is out of date. Thoughts?

Comment: @oɔɯǝɹ I believe you have a valid point as well. If I was in this situation, since Gary's original answer was not wrong, I might have added an answer like yours but not downvoted the other answers. It's possible the downvote is what prompted Gary to come back into this question in the first place and update his original with a similar answer as to what you provided.

Comment: I honestly don't see how an edit could have been moderated as ```conflicting with the original authors intent``` My intent was to provide an answer that showed the original poster how to do Code Coverage in Pester.  At the time, this wasn't possible, but I showed where the information could be found when it was available.

Answer (score 3):

**The current version of Pester (3.0) does support code coverage.**

Simply use

```
Invoke-Pester -CodeCoverage *.ps1
```

to get a full rapport of code coverage (coverage %) and a summary of all the code lines (branches) not executed during testing:

```
Tests completed in 10.11s
Passed: 66 Failed: 0 Skipped: 0 Pending: 0

Code coverage report:
Covered 99,20 % of 501 analyzed commands in 22 files.

Missed commands:

File                  Function          Line Command
----                  --------          ---- -------
Set-ProgressColor.ps1 Set-ProgressColor   19 Write-Verbose "Progress colors are only supported on the PowerShell com...
```